# What is the probability that either $A$ or $B$ occur but not both of them

Tags: probability, probability-theory

$\{A,B,C\}$ are independent events and if $\Pr(A) = \frac{1}{2}$ , $\Pr(B) = \frac{1}{4}$ and $\Pr(C) = \frac{1}{5}$, then what is the probability that either $A$ or $B$ occur, not both.

I got $\frac {5}{8}$ as my answer but my professor got $\frac{1}{2}$ which I don't understand considering I used the correct formula for finding this if $A$ and $B$ are independent events

$$\Pr(A \text{ disjoint } B) = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)$$ and since the events are independent, then $$\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A) \times \Pr(B).$$

Comment: What is the relevance of $Pr(C)$ when the events are independent?

Comment: What has $C$ got to do with it?

Comment: You did not use the correct formula. $P[A \overline{B} + \overline{A}B] = {1 \over 2} {3 \over 4} + {1 \over 2} {1 \over 4} = {1 \over 2}$.

Comment: Sorry I meant to add another question that required C but guess it would be unfair to incorporate it now

Comment: Another case of premature submission.

Comment: sometimes for teaching purposes, including $C$ is to capture students who try to use every single number that appear on the question to make up a final solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have computed the probability that $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$.

What you are interested would be $P(A \cup B)-P(A \cap B)=\frac58 -\frac18=\frac12$

The event of interest is $A \setminus (A \cap B)$ and $B \setminus (A \cap B)$ which are disjoint, hence the probability would be $$P(A \setminus (A \cap B))+P(B \setminus (A \cap B))=P(A)-P(A \cap B) + P(B)-P(A \cap B) = P( A \cup B)-P(A \cap B)$$